# Complete example of a PCF Tile with an addon

Tags: pcf, cf-bosh

Are there any tutorials dealing with Pivotal Cloud Foundry Tile containing addons? I see code snippets of what goes into a Tile manifest but no comprehensive examples or tutorials.

Comment: Did you try the tile developer guide? https://docs.pivotal.io/tiledev/2-3/index.html

Comment: @johnrsharpe, thanks for the reply. I'm looking for complete examples to fix a problem.

The documentation is where I started. 

When trying to deploy I see from the Ops Manager's log:

W, [2018-11-15T00:21:26.418642 #842]  WARN -- : Error in step runner run method (will show -1 as exit code): undefined method `file' for nil:NilClass
/home/tempest-web/tempest/web/app/models/persistence/models/product.rb:355:in `release_file_path'

So, I mis-named something in my tile.yml but don't know where the problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you have a very specific problem, which would potentially be on topic, but the question you've asked is very broad. Give a [mcve] that focuses on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for reading my question and trying to answer. As it turns out, the naming for a Tile manifest must exactly match that in the Release being included. The Tile now deploys successfully.